# need help in modifying code to access YOLOv5 for CPU

Tags: opencv, pytorch, object-detection, yolo

I am trying to implement a object detection program with Pytorch , OpenCV and YOLOv5 that detect the objects and the type of object from a YouTube video . However, while running, the output console shows that the YOLO version the program is trying to run is for CUDA . I wish to use the YOLO for CPU to implement the project as my computer is not set up for CUDA. I seek assistance on how may I go about modifying the program to utilize the YOLO for CPU ? Thank You Very Much !

Link to GitHub Gist

https://gist.github.com/neitherjames/c3b91033eca3794f8170ee51ee5357d4

Comment: Please post the relevant code snippets in your post instead of providing external links.

Answer (score 1):

From your `__init__` it shows that you give the system the option to choose CUDA if it is available. You can force it to run on cpu by stating `self.device = 'cpu'` on line 23. Then when calling `self.model.to(self.device)` on line 48, the model is sent to cpu.